# How to Make Drop down pagination in Yii framework?

Tags: yii

I want to make Drop down pagination in yii frame work, any sugession will be helpfull. thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always do a google search to find examples like these: http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/pagination/basicPager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code..

In your contrller:

```
 public function actionAdmin(){         
if (isset($_GET['pageSize'])) {
 Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSize',(int)$_GET['pageSize']);
 unset($_GET['pageSize']);}
    $model=new Packages('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes(); 
    if(isset($_GET['Packages']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Packages'];       
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Packages'); 
    $this->render('admin',array('model'=>$model,'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

and in model search function use this

```
return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this),array(
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
            ),
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
```

in your view use this

```
$pageSize=Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']); 

echo CHtml::dropDownList('pageSize',$pageSize,array(10=>10,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100,500=>500,1000=>1000),array('onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('packages-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})",'empty'=>'-- Select Page Range --','style'=>'width:198px;'));
```

now dropdown pagination implemented in your yii project.

Comment: I forgot mention. Also assign page parameter in config file. like this. `'params'=>array('defaultPageSize'=> '10'),`

Comment: Thanks dear,Problem Solved,some little bit issues but I  had fix them,

Comment: I am also working on same thing but I need to apply the same code for 10 grids in a same project. Now my issue is if I will select any value from drop down then selected value is getting set for all grids. Can you please help me to solve the same

Comment: change pageSize with grid id like pageSizeMyGrid

Comment: Thanks for reply. where to change? in all places!

Comment: Thanks it is working for me. I need one more help. When I will be selecting value from drop down on one page and after that I am loading another page and again I will be loading old page then drop down value is not getting reset to default value